# JavaFx: Bidirectional Binding, selected value in TableView

Tags: javafx, properties, binding, tableview, bidirectional

I need some help, im trying to bind properties of an object in my model with some labels and textfields.

```
label1.textProperty().bind(myModel.getSelectedObject().getNameProperty());
```

in this case `getSelectedObject()` is the selected Object in a TableView. Somehow this doesn't work as expected. When the model's value changes, the label doesn't change.

I mangaged to fix this issue with the `Bindings` help class:

```
label1.textProperty().bind(Bindings.select(myModel.getSelectedObject(), "name"));
```

Only with the `Bindings` help class the label's text gets binded correctly to the name-property of the object.

now im trying to get the same result with a bidirectional binding. Anyone any ideas?

If i bind it like this, it has no effect (same as first code-snipped)

```
textField.textProperty().bindBidirectional(myModel.getSelectedObject().getNameProperty());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ChangeListener` for `SelectionModel` enable to switch binding. Try it out.

```
tableView.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener((o, ov, nv) -> {
    if (ov != null) textField.textProperty().unbindBidirectional(ov.nameProperty());
    if (nv != null) {
        textField.setDisable(false);
        textField.textProperty().bindBidirectional(nv.nameProperty());
    } else {
        textField.setDisable(true);
        textField.setText("");
    }
});
```

NOTE:

In case selected item is removed from `TableView`'s items, This `ChangeListner` is called with removed item as `oldValue` rather than null. So no needs to care removal of list item .